# Select input don't show in request

Tags: php, forms, symfony, select, request

it's my first post and i'm french so sorry if i mess a little.

Im working on a symfony project, i have a bunch of select inputs in a form and when i submit the form without choosing any options in my selects, they appear in the parameters of my request.
[form visual empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn1jv.png)

```
CustomerController.php on line 203:
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request {#48 ▼
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#93 ▶}
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#88 ▼
    #parameters: array:4 [▼
      "select_1" => "0"
      "select_2" => "0"
      "select_3" => "0"
      "button" => ""
    ]
  }
```

But when i try to fill my form, they disappear from my request dump :
[form filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g9c7.png)

```
CustomerController.php on line 203:
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request {#48 ▼
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#93 ▶}
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#88 ▼
    #parameters: array:2 [▼
      "select_2" => "0"
      "button" => ""
    ]
  }
```

Here is a part of my view :

```
{% if headers is defined %}
  {% set head_cpt = 1 %}
  {% for head in headers %}
    {% if head is not null %}
      {% set field_cpt = 0 %}
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="select_{{head_cpt}}">{{head}} :</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <select class="field_selector" name="select_{{head_cpt}}" onchange="refresh_values(this)">
          {% for field in FIELDS %}
          <option value="{{field_cpt}}">{{field}}</option>
          {% set field_cpt = field_cpt + 1 %}
          {% endfor %}
        </select></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    {% endif %}
    {% set head_cpt = head_cpt + 1 %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<div class="col-md-2">
  <button type="submit" name="button">Importer</button>
</div>
```

Can someone help me ? Tell me if you need me to show any other part of my code !
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing the form fields disappear from the request when you submit the form. So can you show us how you handle the form?